# MSMQ Event Logging doesn't show dropped messages?

Tags: c#, windows, msmq

So I'm trying to get MSMQ messages forwarded from one machine to another (which is dead easy - I was surprised), but one of the requirements from the ops side of the house is that we need to be able to see a log entry somewhere when the remote server decides not to accept a message.  For example, if I try to send to a nonexistent queue, like so:

```
MessageQueue remoteQueue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:Direct=OS:machinename\private$\notarealqueue");

remoteQueue.Send("Test", MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

The message goes into the local delivery queue, and appears to get sent across the network, but because the queue doesn't exist, the remote MSMQ manager discards the message.  However, there's no entry in the Event Log that I can find about the message being dropped on the floor, and that makes people nervous.  The Microsoft/Windows/MSMQ/EndToEnd log only seems to involve successful messages, which doesn't seem particularly useful.  Is there a log I'm not seeing somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MSMQ dead letter queues for that.

```
message.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;
```

With that enabled, if message can't be delivered it will be sent to one of two system dead letter queues - one for transactional and one for non transactional messages. You'll also find there the reason why message was not delivered, which was the original destination queue, full message body, label, etc.

You can use one of tools for managing queues to resend or recover these messages.

Comment: Turning on negative source journaling was the solution.  It frustrates some of the ops guys to not have the reason in the event log (for ease of monitoring), but at least it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

The event log is solely for the health state of MSMQ. What happens to a single message is trivial and not logged in the event log. Imagine what would happen if a million messages were discarded and had to be logged in the event log.